# error during response creation elasticsearch response from file

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, groovy

I try create response from file for testing elasticsearch service

```
    def "FounderHint"() {
        setup:
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("elastic_response/elastic-founders-hint-response.json")
        SearchResponse response = new SearchResponse().readFrom(url.openStream())  // this is a 40 line error

        when: "we ask for hint"
        elasticClient.search(any()) >> response
        metrics.measureHintSearchTime(_) >> response

        then: "we get list of ObjectHint"
        List<ObjectHint> result = advancedSearchFilter.founderHint("але").collect(Collectors.toList())

        result[0].inn == "323500905646"
        result[0].name == "Алешина Екатерина Леонидовна"
```

but i get error -

```
No signature of method: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse.readFrom() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.BufferedInputStream) values: [java.io.BufferedInputStream@19f135ca]
Possible solutions: readFrom(org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput), readFrom(org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput), readFrom(org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse.readFrom() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.BufferedInputStream) values: [java.io.BufferedInputStream@19f135ca]
Possible solutions: readFrom(org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput), readFrom(org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput), readFrom(org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput)
    at ru.esphere.informator.refbook.retriever.hint.SearchExternalHintServiceTest.test external hint method for receive correct result(SearchExternalHintServiceTest.groovy:40)
```

SearchResponse is a class elasticsearch and it does not have setters, are there other ways to create a response or where did I make a mistake?

Comment: From the error it is evident that "url.openStream()" is returning a "java.io.BufferedInputStream". Whereas, readFrom() is applicable for org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.
Why don't you try creating a StreamInput from BufferedInputStream?

Comment: I tried url.newInputStream() thats returns BufferedInputStream, but it didn't help me, the error is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedInputStream stream = url.openStream()
    SearchResponse response = new SearchResponse().readFrom(new StreamInput(stream))
```

The BufferedInputStream from the first line is transformed into StreamInput, before passing it to readFrom

Comment: I do not write "new StreamInput" because it is abstract class, if you meant casting types, it doesn't work either